# Error 1009-handling

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling

I want to make counterdown in quiz. In my quiz, after endtime it will go to another frame. The time is about 10 minutes, exactly. In this code I just write in 31 second to make it simple.
This is my code

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

stop()

var totSec:int = 31;
var totTime:Number = 1000 * totSec;

var secTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,totSec);
secTimer.start ();
secTimer.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, updateClock);

function updateClock (t:TimerEvent) {
    var timePassed:int = totTime - getTimer();
    var second:int = Math.floor(timePassed/1000);
    var minute:int = Math.floor(second/60);
    //trace ("second : " + second);
    second %= 60;
    var sec:String = "";
    sec = String(second);

    if (second < 10)
    {
        sec = "0" + second;
    }
    var showTime:String = minute + " : " + sec;
    timeDisplay.text = String(showTime)
    if (minute == 0 && second == 0 )
    {
        gotoAndPlay(525);
        //addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, stopTime);
        trace ("Times up");
        secTimer.start ();

    }
}
```

But, when the frame go to frame 525, I get this error

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at adminserver/updateClock()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The issue:

Your timer actually ticks one more time after you do the following:

```
    gotoAndPlay(525);
    //addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, stopTime);
    trace ("Times up");
    secTimer.start();  <---------not sure what this is about?
```

So when it ticks again, you've actually gone to a different frame (525) where your `timeDisplay` text field no longer exists (presumably) - so the code errors.

*when you change frames, code attached to listeners keeps running even if that code wasn't on the current frame*

### The Cleanest Solution

Instead of doing your own math to figure out when the timer is done, use the actual timer event for such:

```
secTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, .....
```

This way, you know the timer is done before your code runs and you change frames.

Here is a full example, along with some tips:

```
        stop();

        var totSec:int = 31;

        //no need for this var, total time in your case is secTimer.repeatCount * secTimer.delay
        //var totTime:Number = 1000 * totSec;

        var secTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,totSec);

        secTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateClock);
        //listen for the complete event when the timer is all done
        secTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);
        secTimer.start();

        function updateClock (e:TimerEvent) {
            //the timer's currentCount will be how many times the timer has ticked, 
            //which in this case will be seconds elapsed. 
            //If you subtract that from the total repeat count, you'll get the seconds left, 
            //no need to use getTimer, which is now allows you to pause your timer if you'd like (can't pause using getTimer)
            var second:int = secTimer.repeatCount - secTimer.currentCount;

            var minute:int = Math.floor(second/60);
            //trace ("second : " + second);
            second %= 60;
            var sec:String = String(second);

            if (second < 10){
                sec = "0" + second;
            }
            var showTime:String = minute + " : " + sec;
            timeDisplay.text = String(showTime);
        }

        function timerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void {
                trace ("Times up");

                //secTimer.start();  //you don't really want to start the timer again - which does nothing anyway without a secTimer.reset() first
                //you should also remove the listeners on the timer so it can freed for garbage collection
                secTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateClock);
                secTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);

                gotoAndPlay(525);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that to avoid that error, you should stop that `Timer` before going to another frame :

```
// ...

trace ("Times up");
secTimer.stop();

gotoAndPlay(525); 

// ...
```

Hope that can help.